# How to drag down data in already filled column in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel file filled with data and formatted in a specific structure where a data record could consist of several rows.
Something like that:

```
Records:|| Date:      || Property:||
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
Record1 || 31/07/2017 || Property1||
------------------------------------
        ||            || Property2||
------------------------------------
        ||            || Property3||
------------------------------------
Record2 || 17/06/2019 || Property1||
------------------------------------
        ||            || Property2||
------------------------------------
Record3 || 17/06/2019 || Property1||
```

I would like to "drag down" the date values so every row to contain them (to not have "Property"-s with empty "Date" cells).

Let's say, the logic should be: "Take a date value and fill down every empty cell under it in this column. When you find new date value, continue the drag down process with it."

I've seen such implementations using data processing scripts but for the current task I'm limited by the technology and time.

Is there a way to do the task using only Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**Step 1:** Filter only blank cells in column `Date` or `Records`

[image]

**Step 2:** Set the formula in the top blank cells to get the value of the cell above them **relatively**. For example, set the formula for `A3` is `=A2` and `B3` is `=B2`

[image]

**Step 3:** Copy down that formula for all blank cells (Ctrl + D)

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Unfilter to see all cells:

[image]

Comment: I suggest to copy and paste the whole table as value to fix the result.

Comment: Thank you!The solution is handy and very useful!